# How to solve conflict in jQuery when used in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Below is the references and script I am using in the same page for date time picker and colour box. Only either one of them works when commenting the other script referenced. I thought it may be due to conflict to used jQuery noconflict. But this didn't help.

How can this be solved ?

```
        <%--DATE AND TIME PICKER--%> 
       <%-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Uploadedfiles/System/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

        <%--COLOR BOX--%> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox/colorbox.css" media="screen, projection" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("[id*=txtfromdate]").datepicker();
            $("[id*=txttodate]").datepicker();
            $("[id*=txtClosingDate]").datepicker();

            $("[id*=txtTimestart]").timepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
            });

            $("[id*=txtTimeend]").timepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
            }); 
        });

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        function colorbox() {
            var hv = $("[id*=txt_Messsage]").val();
            $.colorbox({ width: "50%", height: "30%", html: hv })
            alert(hv);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Look for [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: hey colorbox is Jquery UI plugin ? if it is how it can create conflict ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, As you have suspected correctly, it might be the situation that some of the functions
might be present in two of your JQuery files that might have been creating that conflict.

Solutions: 1) Try to identify which of the function is common between your jQuery files
            Or else Try to use a single jQuery file and copy the additional functions that 
            you need to one of the jQuery files.
           2) else use `jQuery.noConflict();` inside

this `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$.noConflict();` before the code that might create conflict

Refer this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

As an **addition** to others answers ,

Once you do : 
`$.noConflict();` you are back to `jQuery` ( and not to the dollar sign)

But you can also do :

```
var _=$.noConflict();
```

And now you can use `_("#myId")...`

NB you might need the overload :

```
jQuery.noConflict( [removeAll ] )
```

> A Boolean indicating whether to remove all jQuery variables from the
>   global scope (including jQuery itself).